# Sencha Touch 2.0.0 - store.load not calling on pagingation

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Hi I am new to Sencha touch and using `Ext.dataview.DataView` to display a list of products.

I am using plugin `Ext.plugin.ListPaging` for automatic pagination.
In constructor of my `Ext.dataview.DataView` class, I am creating an instance of `store` and adding an event listener on it.

```
var store = Ext.create('MyApp.stores.Products', sale);
store.load(function(results) {
// My implementation here
});
```

Every thing is working perfect, except the `store.load` event is called only once first 25 records are fetched. When user scrolls down, more records are populated in list but `store.load` doesn't call again.

I need to add some custom code in `store.load`.

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you add an event listener.  Your code is just adding a callback function which will only get called once.

```
store.on('load', function(){
      // your implementation
}, this);
store.load();
```